# How to add scss file as styleUrl in component?

Tags: sass, angular

I am wondering if it is possible to add `.scss` file in my component in Angular 2?

Let's say I have the following:

```
@View({
  template: `
     <div class="button" [ng-class]="{active: isOn, disabled: isDisabled}" 
         (click)="toggle(!isOn)">
         Click me!
     </div>`,
  styleUrl: ['style.scss'],
  directives: [NgClass]
})
```

Is compiling the scss file to css the only way to achive what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: change `ng-class` to `ngClass` you are wrong here... also you can add `.scss` file by using this method `@import "yourfilePath";`

Comment: Browsers don't support scss files, so you'll have to compile them to css. You can either load stylesheets or embed them with tools like webpack, [gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular2-embed-sass/) and similar.

Comment: It is possible, but you need to make server able to support this type of files, e.g. compile them during request (maybe take precompiled from cache) and respond with CSS. Another option is to use `styles` instead of `styleUrls` and require SCSS with bundler like webpack: `styles: [require('style.scss')]`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you need to make server able to support this type of files, e.g. compile them on the fly during request, or maybe take precompiled CSS files from cache. In any case, the response when you navigate to

```
GET /approot/component/path/style.scss
```

needs to be valid `text/css` type. By default no webserver is going to do it. It is totally possible with Express, Apache, etc. but it requires configuration.

Another option is to use `styles` instead of `styleUrls` and require SCSS with bundlers like webpack:

```javascript
styles: [require('style.scss')]
```

Above should work, but the notation is not that nice.

Finally, I would probably go with

```javascript
styleUrls: ['style.css']
```

... and use SCSS for development, making sure my watch/build task compiles scss->css and puts `style.css` just next to `style.scss` in the same directory (on in the `dist`, wherever it needs to be). So you work with SCSS and never touch generated CSS, which is there only to be consumed by app.

Comment: Isn't `styleUrls`, instead of `styleUrl` ?

Comment: I create my ng2 component in a separate npm package, then use it in my app. I have my `style.scss` file along with the component sources. I tried both `[require('./style.scss')]` and your code, but both of them complain that `Cannot find module style.scss`. How do I *export* this scss file to my app, so that its webpack can compile it along with other sources and style files?

Answer (score 0):

`styleUrls` for now must be only css files list, so you need to provide the name of `.css` file to apply for components, so simple to think about provide the name of compiled `.css` file from `.scss` file, I found very helpful link to make that and with very well explained example:

http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-sass/

This even should work in long term, hopefully the angular 2 somehow support the `.scss` and internally compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend adding scss files through import:

import 'style-loader!./your-scss-file-name.scss';

make sure the file url is correct.